# .img file restore to disk partition

Tags: dd, disk-image

I had created a backup.img file from a hard disk having two partitions. Now I want to write these partitions to another hard disk. But the problem is I don't know how?
If I use dd than it write the complete backup.img file to one partition and then I see nothing there. Please help.

Edit 1
dd if = /XXX/backup.img of = /dev/sdb1

Actually sdb have many partitions so I can not write backup.img to complete disk.

Comment: Which dd command are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you made the image of the whole drive for example `/dev/sdb` then you should restore it to a whole drive.
- But if you made the image of a partition for example  `/dev/sdb1`, then you should restore it to a partition.

You can check for the content of the image file with `kpartx`. It can see directory structure, if there is one (and not only a file system sitting at the head end of the image). See this example,

Map:

```
$ sudo kpartx -av t-3.5g.img
add map loop0p1 (253:0): 0 6293372 linear 7:0 503907
add map loop0p2 (253:1): 0 1954 linear 7:0 1953
add map loop0p3 (253:2): 0 500000 linear 7:0 3907
```

Delete map:

```
$ sudo kpartx -d template-3.5GB.img
```

Please notice that the devices for partitions will probably look like this, when seen by other tools:

```
/dev/mapper/loop0p1
...
```

Another example,

```
$ sudo kpartx -av lubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso
add map loop0p1 (253:0): 0 2345472 linear 7:0 0
add map loop0p2 (253:1): 0 4928 linear 7:0 2314176

$ lsblk -f /dev/loop0
NAME      FSTYPE  LABEL                     UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0     iso9660 Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS amd64 2020-08-06-23-08-05-00               
├─loop0p1 iso9660 Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS amd64 2020-08-06-23-08-05-00               
└─loop0p2 vfat                              EC34-71CF                            

$ lsblk -f /dev/mapper/loop0p1
NAME    FSTYPE  LABEL                     UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0p1 iso9660 Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS amd64 2020-08-06-23-08-05-00
```

When you know what you have, you will also know how to clone the content. But it is also possible to mount a mapped source partition and the target partition and extract files (copy them with `rsync` or some other program).

Comment: image have two partitions

Comment: If you have an image of a partition it is straightforward to clone like you suggest in Edit 1 of your question (but of course to the correct target partition. If there are several partitions in the image, you can clone a partition for example `/dev/mapper/loop0p1` to a suitable target partition. But you can also mount the source and target partitions and copy files, for example with `rsync`. Please notice that the target partition must be at least as big as the source partition.

Comment: Well thanks It cleared my concept about mounting too. i was struggling for last few hours.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck finding the correct source and target for your cloning operation :-) Please remember to douple-check that the command line is correct before pressing the Enter key.