# Disk Image Mounter does not show hidden files/folders when it opens an ISO file

Tags: mount, iso, disk-image, hidden-files, disk-utility

I archived a lot of files and folders into a .img file... it is a disk image I made using dd and rsync. I then made an .iso file from the .img file (using ImgBurn in Windows 10).

Using Caja file explorer in Ubuntu... When I double click on the .img file it opens with "Disk Image Mounter" and I can see all the files and folders including hidden files and folders (starting with a dot ".")

Now from Caja I right click on the iso file and choose to open-with "Disk Image Mounter" from the right click menu. However this way the hidden files and folders are not visible in Caja.

I know there is a command to mount the iso file from Terminal such that the hidden files in the iso are visible BUT I am not interested in that method. I only want to use Disk Image Mounter from Caja file explorer.

My question is:
"Why does **Disk Image Mounter** NOT show hidden files/folders by default in an ISO file but it DOES show hidden files/folders in a .img file"?

Comment: I am leaving this as a comment because it does not fully answer the question. I found that re-creating the ISO file from the IMG file with mkisofs works. When I open that ISO file with Disk Image Mounter then the hidden files ARE displayed in Caja. Example command: `mkisofs -v -J -l -R -V "ISO-Label" -iso-level 4 -o output-file.iso /img/file/mount/point` The problem may be the settings I used with the `ImgBurn` utility in Windows 10 when making the original ISO file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

1. select ISO file in Caja;
2. do right mouse click on it, select *Open With* → *Disk Image Mounter* (or mount it by *Disk Image Mounter* with double click if it is default application);
3. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files (or *View* → *Show Hidden Files*).

About "why" part - it seems to be by design. Caja respects the user-selected *Show Hidden Files* option for folders.

Comment: Thanks for answering but you didn't read my question closely enough... I said that double clicking on the .img file in Caja DOES show hidden files/folders. In other words, I already went to Caja - View - Show Hidden Files. And yet still I do NOT see the hidden files when I use Disk Image Mounter to open an ISO file. And yes I checked again and "Show Hidden Files" IS selected in the Caja View menu.

Answer (score 1):

After some more investigation I have found that:

1. Re-creating the ISO file from the IMG file with the mkisofs command works. Example command: `mkisofs -v -J -l -R -V "ISO-Label" -iso-level 4 -o output-file.iso /img/file/mount/point`. It creates an ISO file system of type CDFS that Disk Image Manager (DIM) can open and the hidden files and folders are visible in Caja.
2. I also found that this works when I re-created the ISO file using ImgBurn and built it with the "ISO9660 + Joliet" file systems only. i.e: leaving out the UDF file system. This also creates an ISO file system of type CDFS.

So it may be that Disk Image Mounter has problems recognizing the MS Windows "Hidden file" attribute in an ISO file built with a UDF file system. I googled for a while but don't know where I can post this issue for review by someone who understands the inner workings of Disk Image Mounter.